# I got this exception: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#

I want to make a management program with an SQL database attached.
My problem is that I want to gather all the values ​​from one column to a textbox.
That column [7] from the datagridview has values ​​based on the calculation of 2 other columns [4]and [5] in the same datagridview formated as money.

I tried to convert it to string or int without success. Please Help!

```
    public void gridTotal()
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
        }
        facturaTotal.Text = sum.ToString("C");
    }
```

Comment: What does the string value look like before you attempt to convert it to double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value
```

may be `null` or empty `String` or something else, which cannot be converted into double. Instead I would recommend

```
double val = 0;
if (double.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value, out val)) sum += val;
```

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I got the CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'


I tried the code below, but val value remained 0.

public void gridTotal()
        {
            double sum = 0, val=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (double.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString(), out val))
                {
                    sum += val;
                }
            }
             facturaTotal.Text = sum.ToString("C");
}

Comment: @DanielRusu "val value remained 0" then it is quite possible that there are some white characters or other content-related problems that prevent the conversion.

Comment: Thanks Lajos Arpad you were right they were some white characters that prevented the conversion. I got rid of them and now it works perfectly.

Comment: @DanielRusu you are welcome. I'm happy the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells contain real numbers written with a dot, like `2.3`, this error will occur. It is common mistake, you should use `CultureInfo` to avoid this problem.

```
sum += Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I got the CS1503: 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' and 

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' to 'System.Globalization.NumberStyles'